# Bootstrap apply true full screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**My HTML**

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="left-top"><a>Aanmelden</a></div>
            <div class="left-bottom"><a>Inloggen</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x310" alt="" class="welcome-image"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="right-top"></div>
            <div class="right-bottom"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[class^=left], [class^=right]').on('click', function () {
            $(this).addClass('fullscreen');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Whenever a button is clicked I'd like the parent square to go fullscreen,
problem is:

- When using `width:100%` it takes 100% of the `.col-md-3`
- When I use jQuery to remove the `.col-md-3` class from the parent the
  whole page blows up.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/odfaf0jg/3/)**

Is there any way to achieve full screen whilst keeping the rest intact ?

*Thanks,
g3*

Comment: you could try overriding the parents position: relative until the button takes the whole body. is that an option?

Comment: It still didn't take full width and it got placed behind the rest of the elements

Comment: set z-index to something higher like 1000 or so

Comment: and work your way up through the dom try setting every position: relative to position: static. I dont know how deep your buttons are nested, so i dont know if this is the right approach

Comment: Well it's close, but the other elements in the same `.col-md-3 ` are jumping out of the screen

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/odfaf0jg/)

Comment: Be sure to run it in fullscreen as bootstrap stacks things in mobile form

Comment: Nevermind the fullscreen part, jsfiddle doesn't do bootstrap

Comment: new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/odfaf0jg/3/)

Comment: Try with this fiddle on bootply : http://www.bootply.com/xvKoNyDYm0

Comment: The new fiddle also has bootstrap ^^ apparently fiddle now has a menu where you can include external css and js

Comment: @YenneInfo it works but I'd like the other elements to just sit in their normal place

Comment: have a look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/odfaf0jg/4/. is this what you had in mind?

Comment: YEAAAAAS! this kicked me into the right direction, I could kiss you right now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/DfNnqvTcRL

**JS** :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[class^=left], [class^=right]').on('click', function () {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('parent-fullscreen');
        $(this).toggleClass('fullscreen');
    });
});
```

**Css**:

```
.parent-fullscreen{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2000;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.fullscreen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
}
```

Comment: Exactly this :3 Thanks a lot!